# NDSolve: Normalizing at every step

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

Suppose I have an transport equation with an initial conditions:

```
sol = NDSolve[{D[y[x, t], t] - 4 D[y[x, t], x] == 0, 
              y[x, 0] == 1/Sqrt[2 \[Pi]] Exp[-(x)^2/2], 
              y[10, t] == 0}, 
              y[x, t], {x, -10, 10}, {t, 0, 5}, 
              MaxStepSize -> 0.1];
Plot3D[Evaluate[y[x, t] /. sol], {x, -10, 10}, {t, 0, 2.5}, 
       PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Suppose the packet is actually a probability distribution. The packet is moving to the left, and at some later time, part of the probability density goes out of the left boundary such that the sum of the probability density in the domain [-10,10] is less than 1.

My question is, what should I do such that, at every time step, the sum of the probability density in the domain [-10,10] is 1?

Comment: Isn't it enough to normalize the result _after_ solving the equation?

Comment: @belisarius, you are right if the mentioned question was all I wanted. However, I intended to break down a very complicated question into a simple one. The problem I really want to solve is one in which there are several (chemical) species reacting with each other, and the probability density of some species is going out of the domain through the left boundary, while some other species through the right boundary. Moreover, if I want to monitor the time evolution, normalizing at every step seems to be the only right way.

Comment: Er… You mean you need to normalize `y` at the moment `NDSolve` gets the solution for the first time point and then solve the `y` at the next time point with this solution and so on? …Is it still a PDE-solving issue?

Comment: @xzczd, you are right. I believe it is a genuine PDE-solving problem. At least it involves `NDSolve` :-)

Comment: Is the expected solution assumed to go towards left boundary and grow and grow approaching a dirac delta function?

Comment: @ssch, yes, you are right.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is the solution :

```
CRK4modified[]["Step"[rhs_, t_, h_, y_, yp_]] := 
 Module[{k0, k1, k2, k3, ampli},
  k0 = h yp;
  k1 = h rhs[t + h/2, y + k0/2];
  k2 = h rhs[t + h/2, y + k1/2];
  k3 = h rhs[t + h, y + k2];
  ampli = 
   If[t < 0.2, 1,  6.5 (* 6.5 : manually trimmed ! *)/Total[y]];
  {h, -y + ampli ((k0 + 2  k1 + 2  k2 + k3)/6 + y)}]
CRK4modified[___]["DifferenceOrder"] := 4
CRK4modified[___]["StepMode"] := Fixed

tEnd = 3;
sol20 = NDSolve[
         {  D[y[x, t], t] - 4 D[y[x, t], x] == 0, 
            y[x, 0] == 1/Sqrt[2 \[Pi]] Exp[-x^2/2],
            y[10, t] == 0}, 
         y,
         {x, -10, 10},
         {t, 0, tEnd},
         Method -> {MethodOfLines, 
            Method -> {"FixedStep", "StepSize" -> 0.02,Method -> CRK4modified},
            TemporalVariable -> t
            }
         ][[1]]

Plot3D[Evaluate[y[x, t] /. sol20], {x, -10, 10}, {t, 0, tEnd}, 
 PlotRange -> {Automatic, Automatic, {-0.1, 1}}]
```

[image]

The solution is based on the use of a do-it-yourself algorithm for solving the ODEs used by the PDE. I have token the example of the Runge-Kutta algorithm (CRK4) from the documentation ([here](http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v8/tutorial/NDSolvePlugIns.html), mathematica version 8) and modified it by dividing the solution-vector y (which values are > 0) by `Total[y]`. This maintains constant the area under the curve at each step.

This algorithm is intentionally effective only after t=0.2 second. This permits to adjust a multiplicative constant coefficient on `Total[y]` (6.5 here, try 8 to see the effectiveness of the algorithm, you will see that the height of the wave has a step at t=0.2)

*Few details about the code of the modification of the Runge-Kutta algorithm CRK4 :*

We want to divide the solution-vector by the surface of the curve. The correction factor is  `ampli = If[t < 0.2, 1,  6.5/Total[y]]`; `Total[y]` is proportional to the surface, with a undetermined constant value that I have manually trimmed (the 6.5, which depends on the number of points of the spatial grid)

The term `-y + ampli ((k0 + 2  k1 + 2  k2 + k3)/6 + y)` in the increment of the solution-vector. As we want to multiply the vector (not the increment) by `ampli`, starting from the normal CRK4 increment `(k0 + 2  k1 + 2  k2 + k3)/6`, I have done a translation `+y` -> multiply by `ampli`-> back-translation (`-y`).

Answer (score 1):

NOT a answer.
Here is a no successful attempt. Definitive ?

Mathematica has utilities that permit the user to manage time during temporal simulations.
One can advance forward (and even backward) on a certain amount of time. Between theses intervals, I hope it should  be possible to change the data.

It is documented in http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NDSolveStateData.html#93858351.

I currently use Mathematica 8.0.4., but the functionality I use here are old (maybe Version 5). It is possible that I miss a more recent functionality.

Here is a prolog to this simulation :

```
ndssdata = First[NDSolve`ProcessEquations[{
     D[y[x, t], t] - 4 D[y[x, t], x] == 0,
     y[x, 0] == 1/Sqrt[2 \[Pi]] Exp[-(x)^2/2],
     y[10, t] == 0
     },
   y,
   {x, -10, 10},
   {t, 0, 100}, MaxStepSize -> 0.01, 
   Method -> {MethodOfLines, TemporalVariable -> t}]]
```

then one can simulate the first 1.1 seconds :

```
NDSolve`Iterate[ndssdata, 1.1]
```

here is the code to see the result :

```
ndsol = NDSolve`ProcessSolutions[ndssdata]
Plot3D[Evaluate[y[x, t] /. ndsol], {x, -10, 10}, {t, 0, 1.1}, 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

We can get the actual data from inside the simulator :

```
actualData=ndssdata@"SolutionVector"["Forward"];
ListPlot[actualData]
```

[image]

It seems that we can modify them, for example multiply them by 2 :

```
    Unprotect[NDSolve`StateData]
    ndssdata@"SolutionVector"["Forward"]= 2 ndssdata@"SolutionVector"["Forward"]
    ndssdata@"SolutionDerivativeVector"["Forward"]= 2 ndssdata@"SolutionDerivativeVector"
["Forward"]
    Protect[NDSolve`StateData]
```

but it is not effective : ndssdata@"SolutionVector"["Forward"] is not modified

**EDIT**

At the moment, it seems that to write in `ndssdata@"SolutionVector"["Forward"]`is not a solution.

If one want to stop the simulation, change the data, and resume the simulation, there is the possibility to use ``` NDSolve``ReInitialize ``` :

```
newstate = 
 First @ NDSolve`Reinitialize[
   ndssdata, {y[x, 0] == 2((ndsol[[1, 2]])[x, 2])}] (* 2="normalisation"*)

NDSolve`Iterate[newstate, 2]
```

Result :

```
ndsolnew = NDSolve`ProcessSolutions[newstate]
Plot3D[Evaluate[y[x, t] /. ndsolnew], {x, -10, 10}, {t, 0, 2}, 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: continuation of the simulation]

we see the continuation of the simulation.

Not very good because :
- the time reset to 0 at every `ReInitilization`
- not applicable to each step

We can view the junction of the two parts with the following code (merge the whole + time of first simulation elongated to 2 seconds + no factor 2):

```
(* part 1 : *)
ndssdata = 
  First[NDSolve`ProcessEquations[  
      {  D[y[x, t], t] - 4 D[y[x, t], x] == 0,
         y[x, 0] == 1/Sqrt[2 \[Pi]] Exp[-(x)^2/2],
         y[10, t] == 0},  
      y,
      {x, -11, 10},
      {t, 0, 100},
      MaxStepSize -> 0.01,
      Method -> {MethodOfLines, TemporalVariable -> t}
      ]];
NDSolve`Iterate[ndssdata, 2]
ndsol = NDSolve`ProcessSolutions[ndssdata]
gr1 = Plot3D[Evaluate[y[x, t] /. ndsol],
                {x, -10, 3},{t, 0, 2}, 
                PlotRange -> All,PlotStyle -> Specularity[White, 5]];
tEndPartOne = Last[ndssdata @ "CurrentTime"];  

(* part 2 : *)
newstate = 
 First@NDSolve`Reinitialize[
   ndssdata,  
   {y[x, tEndPartOne] == ((ndsol[[1, 2]])[x, 2])}
   ] 
NDSolve`Iterate[newstate, 3.7]
ndsolnew = NDSolve`ProcessSolutions[newstate]
gr2 = Plot3D[Evaluate[y[x, t] /. ndsolnew],
             {x, -10, 3},{t, 2, 3.7}, 
             PlotRange -> All];  

(* whole :*)
Show[gr1, gr2]
```

[image]

Comment: It's strange that basic manipulation to SolutionVector does not work... Isn't it supposed to be an "ordinary" variable?

Comment: @wdg I'm not used in object programming. Maybe the problem is very basic. I think that `ndssdata@"SolutionVector"["Forward"]` is a field that can be set with =.

Comment: @wdg It seems that `ndssdata@"SolutionVector"["Forward"]`is not modifiable (no example in documentation). Nevertheless, I succeed in modifying data and resume the simulation with `NDSolve\`Reinitialize`. The problem will be that time return to 0 at every reinitialization.

Comment: `Reinitialize` seems to be a nice work-around. Unfortunately, we would have to "glue" the solution manually, and there may be notable discontinuities in the solution.

Comment: @wdg There are no discontinuity (see figure I have just added).  Maybe you have tried to glue the two first part of the answer. Warning : they are not in a "continuous" time interval (first : [0,1.1], second : [2,4]. There was also a factor 2 to simulate renormalisation.

Comment: @wdg I have added the whole code to reproduce the last graphics. It is just above the graphic.