# Modify NDSolve`StateData (if possible)

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, object-oriented

I am trying to solve a PDE that needs to be scaled constantly (refer to [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/22870/ndsolve-normalizing-at-every-step)). @andre suggests I modify `` NDSolve`StateData ``.

Now, the problem is, I'm not used to the object-oriented side of *Mathematica*, and I cannot find any useful materials on *Mathematica*'s "object". For example, to extract the intermediate values I can use `ndssdata@"SolutionVector"["Forward"]`. I don't even know if `ndssdata@"SolutionVector"["Forward"]` is a method or an variable. Assignment like `ndssdata@"SolutionVector"["Forward"]= 2 ndssdata@"SolutionVector"["Forward"]` does not work, i.e. `ndssdata@"SolutionVector"["Forward"]` is not changed after the assignment.

Question in short: how to modify the actual data in `` NDSolve`StateData ``?

Optional: Where can I find materials on complex *Mathematica* objects like `` NDSolve`StateData ``?

Comment: In case you haven't seen [this doc](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NDSolveStateData.html#93858351) or [this one](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NDSolvePlugIns.html)

Comment: It is a good idea to have done this question. It's the continuation of our exchange. I have read the first reference indicated by Michael E2. The second one not so carefully. I know a good part of the .NET tutorial which has nothing to do except that it is object programming too.I'm going to study the 2nd ref of Michael E2

Comment: The first reference of Michael E2 is not the same with mathematica 8 and mathematica 9. I use mathematica 8 ! .I hope that some information in Mathematica 9 works also for Mathematica 8 (concerning component and data strucure of NDSolve)

Comment: @andre I'm not sure the second one will prove as relevant.  It seems to have examples dealing with state data.  For convenience, the corresponding V8 docs are [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v8/tutorial/NDSolveStateData.html) and [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v8/tutorial/NDSolvePlugIns.html)